# How many senders and receivers of a notification are possible in a POSIX message queue

Tags: linux, posix, ipc, message-queue

How many processes can access the same message queue simultaneously? Can a message queue have multiple processes registered for notifications/multiple processes sending notifications?

- I am new learner/user of message queues and couldn't find an answer to this

Comment: Only one process can have a `mq_notify()` handler, but any number can use `mq_send()` and `mq_receive()` on the same queue.

Comment: You can use Pub/Sub if you want many senders and receivers - under MQTT, or Redis or  ZeroMQ or other.

Comment: If you need several receiver to be able to receive the same message, then POSIX message queue is not a solution by itself. It is not forbidden to have several receivers on a POSIX message queue but as soon as one read a message from the queue the message is removed from the queue.